# kubernetes cant run docker image from localhost registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, kubectl

I am trying to run a single docker container using kubernetes

```
cat /path/to/docker/docker.conf

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --live-restore=true --iptables=false --log-opt max-size=100m --log-opt max-file=3  --bip ${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu ${FLANNEL_MTU}
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry localhost:5000"
```

i want to create a local registry as i dont want my images to reside on the public repo.

```
docker run -d -p 5050:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

then i just build my image

```
docker build -f "Dockerfile" -t localhost:5050/myImage .

docker push localhost:5050/myImage
```

both of these work and just to be sure, i can run the image as well

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name myImage --hostname myImage -v /some/path/to/mount:/some/path/to/mount localhost:5050/myImage
```

now i try to do

```
kubectl run myImage --image=localhost:5050/myImage --port=5050
```

but

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
myImage-4227318852-r8z9n   0/1       ErrImagePull   0          6s

kubectl logs myImage-4227318852-r8z9n
Error from server (BadRequest): container "myImage" in pod "myImage-4227318852-r8z9n" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

what am i doing wrong?

```
docker version
 Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
```

and

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.6", GitCommit:"114f8911f9597be669a747ab72787e0bd74c9359", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T13:36:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.6", GitCommit:"114f8911f9597be669a747ab72787e0bd74c9359", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T13:36:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: 1. Try deleting the image from your machine using docker rmi. Then try pulling the image from your repo. 2. You can look at kubelet logs to find out the exact error message while downloading the image.

Comment: Maybe the registry host is just being resolved on the kube-node, not when initiating `kubectl run` -- if so, `kubectl` may fail to find a registry at its `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that kubernetes is trying to resolve `localhost` inside its own container.

To solve the problem, you need to make the registry accessible to kubernetes. This can be done in multiple ways, but one of them is to run the registry *inside* kubernetes, and then provide a proxy so that it can be accessed outside as well.

This process is described in more detail here: https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615

The important steps are as follows:

> 1. Create a registry on minikube
>
> `kubectl create -f kube-registry.yaml`

(kube-registry.yaml can be found here: https://gist.github.com/coco98/b750b3debc6d517308596c248daf3bb1)

> 2. Map the host port 5000 to minikube registry pod
>
> `kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system \
>   $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | \
>   awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000`